# How do I reply to Outlook mail using VBA in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to reply to a selected mail.

The below Excel VBA code creates mail, which does not have the previous conversation (thread) in the body.

```vb
Sub Test_template()
        
    Dim emailApplication As Object
    Dim emailItem As Object
        
    Set emailApplication = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set emailItem = emailApplication.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).ReplyAll
        
    emailItem.bcc = "XYZ.com"
    emailItem.Body = "Hi, have a nice day "
    emailItem.Display
        
    Set emailItem = Nothing
    Set emailApplication = Nothing
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are trying? I have commented the code and provided relevant MSDN links. If you still get stuck then simply ask.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMail As Object

    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    
    '~~> Get MailItem.GetConversation method (Outlook)
    ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.getconversation
    Dim OutlookConversation As Object
    Set OutlookConversation = OutlookMail.GetConversation

    '~~> Conversation.GetTable method (Outlook)
    ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.conversation.gettable
    Dim OutlookTable As Object
    Set OutlookTable = OutlookConversation.GetTable
    
    '~~> Obtains a 2D array from the Table.
    ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.table.getarray
    Dim OutlookAr As Variant
    OutlookAr = OutlookTable.GetArray(OutlookTable.GetRowCount)
    
    Dim OutlookReplyToThisMail As Object
    Set OutlookReplyToThisMail = OutlookMail.Session.GetItemFromID(OutlookAr(UBound(OutlookAr), 0))
    
    Dim MyMessage As String: MyMessage = "Hi, have a nice day "
    
    With OutlookReplyToThisMail.ReplyAll
        .BCC = "XYZ.com"
        .HTMLBody = MyMessage & .HTMLBody
        .Display
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. But got one more doubt. I am unable to insert new line. 
For Eg
Dim MyMessage As String: MyMessage = "Hi," & vbNewLine & "have a nice day "
Output - Hi, have a nice day
Why is vbNewLine not working ?

Comment: Because we are using that text in HTML body where `vbNewLine` doesn't mean anything. Try this. `MyMessage = "Hi," & "<br>" & "have a nice day "`

Comment: This works well until you have emails with very similar subject lines. The `GetConversation` method seems to select an older email.

Answer (score 0):

`.ReplyAll` produces the expected result but is overwritten by `emailItem.Body = "Hi, have a nice day "`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test_template()
    
    Dim emailApplication As Object
    Dim emailItem As Object
    
    'Set emailApplication = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    ' mail has to be slelected in Outlook application so it has to be open already
    Set emailApplication = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    Set emailItem = emailApplication.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).ReplyAll
    
    emailItem.BCC = "XYZ.com"
    
    'emailItem.Body = "Hi, have a nice day "
    
    emailItem.Body = "Hi, have a nice day " & emailItem.Body
    
    ' or
    'emailItem.htmlBody = "Hi, have a nice day " & emailItem.htmlBody
    
    emailItem.Display
    
    Set emailItem = Nothing
    Set emailApplication = Nothing
    
End Sub
```